# Cisco RV345 SSLVPN Switch on the network cant connect to my TFTP server over VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-vpn

I am trying to upgrade a Cisco SG200-50 switch boot code via TFTP over a VPN connection.

My computer/TFTP Server is 172.21.0.3 which is the SSL VPN subnet of the Cisco RV345 router I am using.

The RV345 Router is at 172.21.39.5

The SG200-50 is at 172.21.39.10

The VPN is a split tunnel affair that excludes local area network so I can use my printer and access my server. It works fine.

When in the SG200 switch web interface I select upgrade firmware, I select my IP address as 172.21.0.3 and the correct boot code filename and hit upload then it tells me it can not connect to my TFTP server.

I have tried to add a static routes on the router of 172.21.0.3 255.255.255.255 172.21.0.1 the direct subnet of the SSLVPN Tunnel also tried 172.21.0.0 255.255.255.0 172.21.39.5 which is the route to the network of the SSLVPN and the routers IP address.

Neither route add worked, I would love to be able to update this stuff remotely over SSLVPN if someone has something they could add I would really appreciate it.